# Programatically untick generate automatic URL alias for new node

Tags: 8

I am creating a new node and then adding a new menu link. I have the code to correctly add the new node and menu link (below).

```
$node = Node::create([
              'type' => 'standard_page',
              'langcode' => 'en',
              'created' => REQUEST_TIME,
              'changed' => REQUEST_TIME,
              'uid' => 1,
              'title' => 'new_node',
              'body' => [
                'summary' => 'new_node',
                'value' => 'new_node',
                'format' => 'full_html',
              ]
          ]);

  $node->save();

$source = '/node/' . $node->get('nid')->value;  \Drupal::service('path.alias_storage')->save($source, '/new_node', 'en');

$link = MenuLinkContent::create([
      'title'      => $title,
      'link'       => ['uri' => 'internal:/new_node'],
      'menu_name'  => 'main',
      'weight'     => 10,
    ]);
```

The problem is that when I go to edit the node, "generate automatic url alias" is always ticked. So whenever I go to update the node, it destroys the alias that I have already created.

I have tried the following code.

```
$node->path['pathauto'] = FALSE;  
$node->save();
```

This doesn't seem to work in Drupal 8 as I get the following error:

> InvalidArgumentException: Unable to set a value with a non-numeric delta in a list. in Drupal\Core\TypedData\Plugin\DataType\ItemList->set() (line 112 of core\lib\Drupal\Core\TypedData\Plugin\DataType\ItemList.php).

Hoe do I programatically untick the "Generate automatic URL alias" option in Drupal 8?

Answer (score 14):

Save your node twice, once to generate the alias and the second time to turn off that option for the node.

```
 // Save node to generate alias
 $node->save();
 // Turn off pathauto
 $node->path->pathauto = 0;
 // Save again.
 $node->save();
```

Then open edit form and " Generate automatic URL alias" will be unchecked.

Comment: Should also work when you save just once. Set $node->path->alias = '/foo'; and ->pathauto = 0 and save.

Comment: Thank you so much for that. I tried for ages to figure that out on my own. If only I would have asked the question sooner...

Comment: Anyone have a reference for me to look into why `path` is available off of the node entity and why `pathauto` is available off of `$node->path`? Are these just magic methods/properties? By reviewing the code, how would I know these exist?

Comment: Tried tons of methods, that's the only one who worked as expected. This should be the accepted answer